# Device Incompatibility List

Tags: pi-2, pi-3, hardware, compatibility, pi-1

Here goes my first question ....

Is there are well maintained list or chart of devices/brands that have known **incompatibilities** with raspberry pi 
either in software (generally fixable or can be worked around) or in hardware (generally harder) ?
I dont mind including poor performance issues as well

I know there is a list of compatible devices over [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) but my question deals with ones that are not 
covered in the list and are known to have issues.

Specifically I am looking for devices under

- Storage - SD / Micro SD, NAS
- USB devices -
- Networking - wifi/bluetooth/ethernet adapters,
- Power Supplies, UPS
- GPIO/SPI/USART/I2C - TFT screens, ADC boards, Temperature/Pressure/Humidity Sensors, Bar Code Scanners
- Cameras
- Audio In/Out
- Displays - specific screens/displays with quirks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I know is http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals which you mention.

I doubt such a list as you want will exist.

The eLinux page covers

```
4 Powered USB Hubs
5 USB Remotes
6 USB Keyboards
7 USB Mouse devices
8 USB Real Time Clocks
9 Internet

    9.1 USB Wi-Fi Adapters
    9.2 USB Bluetooth adapters
    9.3 USB Ethernet adapters
    9.4 USB 3G Dongles
        9.4.1 Huawei
        9.4.2 Sierra Wireless
        9.4.3 ZTE
        9.4.4 Others

10 USB Sound Cards

    10.1 Databases of supported sound cards
    10.2 Class compliant USB sound cards
    10.3 Troubleshooting

11 USB IR Receivers
12 USB Radio devices
13 USB TV Tuners and DVB devices
14 USB Video / Frame grabbers
15 USB Webcams
16 USB GPS devices
17 USB UART and USB to Serial (RS-232) adapters

    17.1 Working USB to Serial Adapters
    17.2 Problem USB to Serial Adapters

18 USB Multi-Card Readers

    18.1 Working USB Multi-Card Readers
    18.2 Problem USB Multi-Card Readers

19 USB Smart-Card Readers

    19.1 Working USB Smart-Card Readers

20 Other, exotic USB devices

    20.1 Joysticks / Joypads
    20.2 Numpads
    20.3 USB to Parallel Port/Printer Adapters
    20.4 USB to IDE/SATA
    20.5 CAN Bus
    20.6 Home automation
    20.7 Weather station
    20.8 One-Wire
    20.9 Touch Screen
    20.10 Floppy Disk Drive
    20.11 USB Missile Launcher
    20.12 USB Docking Stations
    20.13 USB RFID Reader
    20.14 JTAG
    20.15 Tinkerforge Bricks and Bricklets (http://www.tinkerforge.com)
    20.16 Thermometers
    20.17 Fingerprint Scanners
        20.17.1 Futronic

21 PS2 / AT to USB Converters
22 Power Switches
23 Power adapters

    23.1 Working power Adapters
    23.2 Problem power Adapters
    23.3 Working external Battery packs (with 5 V regulated output)

24 LCD touch screen add-ons
25 Display adapters

    25.1 HDMI->DVI-D cables
    25.2 HDMI->VGA Cables
    25.3 HDMI->VGA converter boxes
    25.4 DVI-D -> VGA active adapters
    25.5 Composite->SCART
    25.6 Composite->VGA converter boxes

26 Boblight hardware
27 SD cards
```